# How to copy files from external stage to internal stage in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an AWS Account and I'm using AWS Snowflake.
I'm looking to transfer files from my S3 buckets to Snowflake's internal stages directly.
I initially thought about using the COPY command, but I realized that it requires either input or output is a table, so this approach won't work.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you would want to do this? What difference/impact is there if data is in an internal or external stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a Python Stored Procedure - which you can point to the staged file in S3, and copy to an internal stage:

```sql
create or replace procedure copy_bin(file_url string, dest_stage string, dest_filename string)
returns variant
language python
runtime_version=3.8
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler = 'x'
execute as caller
AS
$$

from snowflake.snowpark.files import SnowflakeFile
import io

    
def x(session, file_url, dest_stage, dest_filename):
    file = io.BytesIO(SnowflakeFile.open(file_url, 'rb').read())
    session._conn.upload_stream(file, dest_stage, dest_filename, compress_data=False)
    return 'file copied to stage [%s] with name [%s]' % (dest_stage, dest_filename)
$$;
```

Call it like:

```sql
call copy_bin(
    build_scoped_file_url(@s3_stage, 'sql.like.replace.png')
    , '@for_images'
    , 'sql.like.replace.png'
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your procedure realized what Iwant to do.